# How to do partial updates using Google.Cloud.Firestore .NET library?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-firestore

Say I have a class Player:

```
[FirestoreData]
public class Player {
 
  [FirestoreProperty]
  public string Name {
    get;
    set;
  }

  [FirestoreProperty]
  public string Score {
    get;
    set;
  }

  [FirestoreProperty]
  public bool Active {
    get;
    set;
  }
}
```

If I try to update only the Score for example:

```
player = new Player {       
    Score = "100"
  }
  .AddAsync(player, SetOptions.MergeAll)
```

`Name` and `Active` get wiped out. So although I only instantiate `Score`, the other properties are just dragged along, and since they have no value attributed in this instance of Player, they end up with null in firestore.

The same result using UpdateAsync (converting player to dictionary).

Would appreciate any lights on how to achieve this.

Comment: Your `Player` class as defined doesn't have a `ScoreID` but you're assigning one in the code? And although `Score` is defined as a string, you're assigning an integer - 100 - to it? Plese try to make the code in your question as close to your actual code as you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to update just a single property is to use the `UpdateAsync` overload that accepts a string:

```cs
await documentReference.UpdateAsync(nameof(Player.Score), "100");
```

Or you could an anonymous type with `SetAsync`:

```cs
await documentReference.SetAsync(new { Score = "100" }, SetOptions.MergeAll);
```

As far as I can remember, we haven't added a facility to perform merging based on actual objects; we could *potentially* have a `SetOptions.MergeAllNonNull` or similar, but it's the kind of thing that gets complex pretty quickly.